# How do I present a ViewController over another with that VC having no knowledge of the new one?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiviewcontroller

I had a method to do this, but it stopped working at some point.

The motivation here is for debugging. I have a button that shows a debugging action sheet from whatever VC calls it. This works great. However, in the action sheet, after I select one, the action wanted is in some cases the presentation of a new VC. The first example of this was a VC that displays my internal log. It's very valuable when not debugging in a "tethered" mode.

Each debugging VC is represented as a scene in the Main storyboard. I instantiate the VC with instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:. Then I am trying to get it presented.

The tricky part is that the new VC has to be presented and then dismissed without writing any code in the VC that is currently active. Neither do I want to create a Segue from every VC where this might be called. The whole point is that the DebugActionSheet is self contained except for the single call to fire it up.

Comment: Check out this github project: https://github.com/ipodishima/PPTopMostController Marian has made a UIViewController category that allows you to call [UIViewController topMostController] and it will return the active UIViewController.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turned out my problem was that the current top controller is using a Navigation controller, so the required code is different.

```
UIStoryboard *story = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"Main" bundle:nil];
_paletteVC = [story instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"PaletteDisplayVC"];

[[_delegate navigationController] pushViewController: _paletteVC
                                            animated: YES];
```

I pass the current top controller to my DebugActionSheet as delegate, so I do not need the topMostController method above. However, I presume it would work with that also.

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to access the top most view controller like this from your ActionSheet delegate method.

```
+ (UIViewController*) topMostController
{
    UIViewController *topController = [UIApplication sharedApplication].keyWindow.rootViewController;

    while (topController.presentedViewController) {
        topController = topController.presentedViewController;
    }

    return topController;
}
```

then in the calling code:

```
[MyDebugController.topMostController presentViewController:myLoggingView
                 animated:YES
               completion:nil];
```

and your `myLoggingView` can dismiss itself by calling

```
[self.presentingViewController  dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES
                       completion:nil]
```

---

Try presenting it on the main thread?

```
dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^ {
    [self presentViewController:vc animated:YES completion:nil];
});
```

Comment: This is a variation of what was working before. I get "Warning: Attempt to present <PT1.PaletteDisplayViewController: 0x7fa7fbd5e070>  on <LoginViewController: 0x7fa7fbc4f8c0> which is already presenting (null)".